# Как реализовать подмену html тегов или слов?

Tags: html, javascript

Допустим, в тексте документа index.html если такой код:

```
<header></header>

<footer></footer>
```

Как реализовать такую вещь, чтобы этот код менялся на, к примеру, такой:

```
<шапка></шапка>

<низ></низ>
```

Comment: @dimkachel, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Найти интересующий элемент `header`

```
el = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0]
```

Ну и дальше от этого плясать. Создать в его родителе элемент `шапка`, найти дочерние узлы, перекинуть их в элемент `шапка`, удалить `header`.